# Having a Database in different data center

Tags: networking, cassandra, cloud

Our entire infrastructure is built in Linode, Singapore region. The problem is that as of now, Linode does not provide any block storage option. We have a 3 node Cassandra cluster which is growing at the rate of 4-5 gb per day. Each node has 192 GB SSD disk allotted to it. Adding a Cassandra node is simple , but it comes at the cost of maintaining it. The rate at which we are growing, we'd be needing 20-30 servers in 3 month time.
Digital Ocean, Singapore region, on the other hand, does have a block storage option. We can simply add more SSD to our servers rather than provision for 30 small servers.
Data is streamed from Kafka and stored in Cassandra. 
What would be the pros and cons of having your Cassandra cluster in a different Data center but in the same country? The latency between the two is about 2 ms. The ratio between reads and writes are roughly 5% Read ops and 95 % write ops.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but keep in mind that fewer but larger nodes come with their own operational problems: repairs take longer, replacing nodes takes longer, I/O capacity of the cluster is lower, etc.

Comment: I second @Ralf comment above, its better to scale outwards rather than upwards. I"m also eluding to the fact that block storage is not locally attach storage. Generally speaking unless it has performance like AWS EBS i01 storage then you will likely start to deal with i/o bottleneck issues, which can cause all sorts of headaches.